# Continous white noise process: Spectral analysis and Time-series

Tags: time-series

Priestley has explained why white noise process has auto-covariance function $R(\tau)=C\delta(\tau)$, (where $\delta$ is dirac-delta fucntion,) as follows: Consider $\epsilon(t)$ is a white-noise process with $E[\epsilon(t)]=0$ and $E[\epsilon^2(t)]=\sigma^2_\epsilon$. Now if we form another stochastic process $U=\int_{a}^{b}g(u)\epsilon(u)du$; we will have $$Var(U)=\sigma^2_\epsilon\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}g(u)g(v)\delta(u-v)dudv .$$ This is where I don't understand this argument. He writes that since the double integral is zero, it is necessary for $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ to be infinite for $Var(U)$ to be meaningful. I don't see how the double integral is zero, becasue the integral actually becomes $\int_{a}^{b}g^2(u)du >0$, which can be zero only if $g(u)=0$. I am not sure what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous-time white noise is a *mythical* process that cannot be observed in nature, only by its effects as it traverses whatever system or mathematical calculation you are using.

If $\varepsilon_t$ is a continuous-time white noise process, then you are absolutely correct when you assert that $E[\varepsilon_t]=0$ and absolutely wrong when you assert that $E[\varepsilon_t^2]=\sigma_\varepsilon^2$. In fact, $$E[\varepsilon_t\varepsilon_{t+\tau}] = R_\varepsilon(\tau) = C\delta(\tau)$$
as you (presumably following Priestley) said in your very first sentence. Bear in mind that Dirac deltas are not ordinary functions, they are *distributions* and they make sense (for ordinary folks like you and me, not the mathematicians lurking in this forum) only in *integrals*. Thus, $\delta(3)$ is *not* the value of the Dirac delta at $3$ and $\delta(0)$ is *not* the value of the Dirac delta at $0$ and claims that $\delta(0) = \infty$ are spurious. What the Dirac delta means is that
$$\int_a^b g(t)\delta(t-c) \,\mathrm dt = g(c)~~ \text{if}~a<c<b~ \text{and}~ g(t)~\text{is continuous at}~c$$
no more and no less (at least for us ordinary folks). The integral above has value $0$ if $c<a$ or $c>b$ and has undefined value if $g(t)$ is discontinuous at $c$.

Turning to your next statement, note that $U$ is not a random *process* but a random *variable* whose mean is
$$E[U] = E\left[\int_a^b g(u) \varepsilon_u \,\mathrm du\right]
= \int_a^b E[g(u) \varepsilon_u]\,\mathrm du = \int_a^b g(u) E[\varepsilon_u]\,\mathrm du = 0.$$ 
I won't bother justifying the interchange of expectation and integration above but trust me; it is valid. Next, note that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(U) &= E[(U-E[U])^2]\\
&= E\left[\int_a^b g(u) \varepsilon_u \,\mathrm du\int_a^b g(v) \varepsilon_v \,\mathrm dv\right]\\
&= \int_a^b\int_a^b g(u) g(v) E[\varepsilon_u\varepsilon_v] \mathrm du\,\mathrm dv\\
&= \int_a^b\int_a^b g(u) g(v) C\delta(u-v) \mathrm du\,\mathrm dv
\end{align}
and not what you claim that Priestly wrote.  *Now*, we get to the crux of the matter:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(U) &= \int_a^b\int_a^b g(u) g(v) C\delta(u-v) \mathrm du\,\mathrm dv\\
&= \int_a^b g(v)\left[\int_a^b g(u) C\delta(u-v) \mathrm du\right]\,\mathrm dv\\
&= \int_a^b g(v)\cdot g(v) C \,\mathrm dv\\
&= C\int_a^b g^2(v) \,\mathrm dv
\end{align}
which is pretty close to what you wrote.

Comment: My problem is with the claim that the $Var(U)$ becomes zero if $C$ is finite. This is not answered here.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta If Priestly _really_ wrote that $E[\epsilon_t^2]=\sigma_\epsilon^2$, it is wrong. If Priestly _really_ wrote $$Var(U)=\sigma^2_\epsilon\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}g(u)g(v)\delta(u-v)dudv,$$ then that is wrong too. If Priestly _really_ wrote that the above double integral has value $0$ unless $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ is infinite, then that is wrong too. So, double-check to make sure that you are not misinterpreting what your book says, and if you have stated matters correctly, apply Dorothy Parker's dictum: "This is not a book to be put down lightly; it should be thrown with great force!